# SwiftUI Mac OS crash due to popover without EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, swiftui

I am using a PopOver in my view. In that view I am doing a FetchRequest to CoreData. It is working fine. It is connected to my `Environment(\.managedObjectContext)`. However, always when I call my popover and reload that view, it is crashing.

I read in another Stack Overflow question, that I have to manually push my objects to that popover. I am trying it and it still crashes. I am using this to call my popover:

```
Button(action:
{
  //Call the PopOver
  self.s_showPopover = true
})
{
  Image("Link")
}
 .padding(.trailing, 16)
 .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
 .popover(isPresented: self.$s_showPopover, content: { PersonFormPopover().environment(\.managedObjectContext, NSManagedObjectContext.current).environmentObject(userData) })
```

Am I sending my objects correctly? The crash only appear when I click the popover one time minimum. If I don't click it, it doesn't crashes.

In my PopOver view I am not even using that Object, or make any request to CoreData. Why is it still crashing? When I reload that view, it shows me the error in my `foreach` when parsing the `FetchRequest`. It looks like that he do not get any objects at all then.

This is my PersonPopOver view, it is just an empty view.

```
struct PersonFormPopover: View {    
    var body: some View {
        Text(/"Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct PersonFormPopover_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PersonFormPopover()
    }
}
```

I get following crash message when loading my view again after the popup.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: Would you show `PersonFormPopover` code?

Comment: @Asperi It is just an empty View I created for testing..

Comment: @Asperi Added it above

Comment: I found out that my FetchRequest is empty when I fetch again after the popover.

Comment: After I made you code snapshot integrated & compilable - it works well. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / macOS 10.15.0. I assume the reason is in some other place.

Comment: Thank you for trying @Asperi I found a debug message when I call my view again after loading which fetch the data: runtime: "SwiftUI: Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b00620>" What is that message?

Comment: Try to pass instead of `NSManagedObjectContext.current` your local context, like `self.currentContext` or how it's named in your view.

Comment: I tried.. added @Environment and pushed that var. Didn't work either. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found a solution. Thanks for the help of @Asperi ...

I was using a NavigationView before my actual view. It looks like SwiftUI is not pushing my `Environment Object` to the `DetailView`. Not sure if it a bug though, however pushing it manually at the `NavigationLink` and `PopOver` fixed it.

Maybe it is helpful for other, when struggling with the same issue.

I just changed my `NavigationLink` to the following code:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: VenueView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, NSManagedObjectContext.current), tag: 4, selection: self.$userData.currentView) {
```

There I am adding the `environment` manually and it works.

My code for the popover looked like this:

```
.popover(isPresented: self.$s_showPopover, content: { PersonFormPopover().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext).environmentObject(self.userData)
```

I used a local var for my managedObjectContext as Asperi suggested.